# most acceptable way to put dynamic html on a page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I would like to append some html to a `div` when a button is clicked. The only thing that needs to be dynamic about it is that it needs to have a different id the the otherwise identical html above it. So if I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="div1" class="inner">
       <p id="P1">Some content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="div2" class="inner">
       <p id="P2">Some content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

and to the end of container i would like to append

```
  <div id="div3" class="inner">
         <p id="P3">Some content</p>
  </div>
```

What would be a good method to store this HTML? Keep it all in a php page and post the number the new div's id should be incremented to? Or is is smarter to put the html inside a string, and have a regular expression increment all of the numbers. Or is there some incredibly obvious way to do this that I've completely missed.

Jquery is an option, as that's already on the page.

Also, if this question seems too open-ended, please let me know in the comments how I can change it before closing it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add teh button text, is it one button only?

Comment: The approach you would take would depend a lot on a few factors:

1) Do you want to do this without reloading the page?
2) Do you know what the HTML content to be inserted in new node is to be before the page is generated? Is it simply a copy of an existing node?
3) Do you really care if there is an id "counter" at all? What is this counter used for?

Comment: So whats the reason for adding ids? for jquery selectors? why not use `this`

Comment: @MikeBrant These are great questions. Thank you. Definitely can't reload the page just to append a div. Yes, I know what the html will be, as it will be identical to the div above it, so yeah, just a copy of an existing node. it's an interesting idea not to give unique ids. I honestly hadn't even considered this. Since it would be used only for identification, there's actually no reason in the world that can't be computed in a loop when the pages form is submitted. Mind blowing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Where do you expect eh contents to come from? It looks to me like the HTML given is just an example, so hard to guesstimate.

Comment: @MartinLyne there is only one button. just a normal button. Yes it will just be static html. basically like what I have above, but longer.

Comment: @thomas You didn't mention anything about a form in your original post.  Will there be form fields in "some content"?  As this may change the approach needed.  Generally the reason I ask, is that when dealing with javascript/jquery node manipulation, it will make thing a little harder if you need to for example count up the number of nodes and change the id as opposed to just cloning and appending the node based on class alone.

Comment: @MikeBrant ha, yeah, that was kind of an important part to leave out. Basically each of these divs will have some inputs for text. that is why the ids would be helpful, they could be something like `order_1_line_item_1`, `order_2_line_item_2`, &c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answers to comments so far (i.e. that the id's aren't really important, and that you will have input elements in the content), I would say that you would want to redo your html to look like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="inner">
       <p><input type="text" name="order_item[]" value="" /></p>
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p><input type="text" name="order_item[]" value="" /></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note there are no longer id's and I have used array notation for your input elements such that they will be posted as an array to the receiving script (eliminating the need to increment counters in javascript or parse different posted variable names into a usable array in PHP on the server).

And then use something like this in jQuery

```
$('#button_id').click(function() {
    $('#container > div.inner:last').clone().val('').appendTo('#container');
});
```

Comment: I think I will go with clone and see if I can make it work without the ids. Novel. I like this. Thanks a million!

Comment: Note the change to my answer based on your comment that you will have form fields within the content.

Comment: Pleas note that with cloning, you will also clone any set value for the form field at the time of cloning, so you might want to adjust your value attribute before appending (I will update code example to reflect this).

Comment: what is the intention of these brackets? `name="order_item[]"`

Comment: @thomas That specifies that the values for that field are to be posted as part of an array called `order_item` (I guess I could have named it `order_items[]` (plural) to make it more clear).  This will save you the headache of having to assemble the different order fields into an array in PHP as you would have to do if you name them like `order_item_1`, `order_item_2`, etc.  For reference you can also name the array index value like `order_items[0]`, `order_items[1]` if so desired, but if you don't care about the order of the items you can save yourself the hassle of needing to specify index.

Answer (score 1):

Put the HTML you want to add each time into a hidden div, then use jQuery to copy and add that to the relevant location. For instance:

```
<div id="appendContents" style="display:none;">
  <div class="inner">
    <p id="P3">Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

then jquery:

```
var shownDivs = <?php echo $numberOnScreenFromBeginning;?>;
$('#theButtonYouWantClickable').click(function()
{
   var newContent = $('#appendContents').clone();
   newContent.$('div.inner').get(0).id = 'div'+shownDivs;
   newContent.$('div.inner p').get(0).id = 'P'+shownDivs;
   // Where does P content come from??
   shownDivs++;
   $('#container').append(newContent);
});
```

Comment: Hidden divs are gross. Why not store a template in some local variable, then parse it with the desired data?!

Comment: I prefer to manipulate Dom compared to parsing strings, but no reason you couldn't turn the template into parsed DOM, then inject the contents (best of both worlds). My example could be amde simpler by not having the hidden anyway, if new div is always a clone of a guaranteed-to-exist div. Just use Div1 from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Please: **Working Demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/eNXmr/

In the code below it will calculate the lenght of the div hence dynamically set the id as 1, 2, 3, and beyond.

Hope it fits you need `:)`

API used: http://api.jquery.com/append/

**Code**

```
  $('#hulk').click(function() {
    alert("Total div inside ==> " + $('#container').find('.inner').length);

    var next_num = parseInt($('#container').find('.inner').length) + 1;

    $('#container').append(' <div id="div' + next_num + '" class="inner"><p id="P' + next_num + '">Some content</p></div>');

});​
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="div1" class="inner">
       <p id="P1">Some content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="div2" class="inner">
       <p id="P2">Some content</p>
   </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Click hulk" id="hulk" />​
```

Comment: This is definitely a tried and true way to do it. And thanks for the counter! These long strings of html (like i know mine will eventually turn into) are just sort of difficult for me to maintain. I suppose now that I think about it, the reason I thought to store all the html in another file and just access it with an ajax call, is just because it looks cleaner and is easier on the eyes. Just sort of canvassing how others do it.. Thanks again!